# User permission to pair with Bluetooth device

Tags: ios, connect, core-bluetooth, user-permissions, pairing

I was reading "[Performing Common Central Role Tasks"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FNetworkingInternetWeb%2FConceptual%2FCoreBluetooth_concepts%2FPerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks%2FPerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html&ei=oQ-5VIOtMIivaabdgcAG&usg=AFQjCNFRpPDex0BabURX3NVMTNnai2r39Q&sig2=ITONDsWuAfHC6Y4iQq3W5w&cad=rja) and it has info on how to discover peripheral and how to connect to peripheral, but I cant seem to find how to check if user selected Cancel or Pair on the popup because the popup comes when I call `[myCentralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];`. I want **not to** connect to (or to disconnect from) peripheral if user clicks Cancel on the Pair popup. Can I call the Pairing popup some other way?

Comment: You shouldn't get a pairing popup until you attempt to read/write a characteristic with encryption required - unless perhaps your peripheral is initiating a pairing on connection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pairing process is initiated by attempting to read/write/notify on a characteristic that requires encryption.

If the pairing process completes then the appropriate `CBPeripheralDelegate` method (e.g. `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:`) will be called with a nil error.

If the pairing process fails or is cancelled then the `CBPeripheralDelegate` method will be called with an NSError object that indicates that 'Encryption is insufficient' - `CBATTErrorInsufficientEncryption`.

If you get the insufficient encryption error you can either disconnect from the peripheral or retry the operation, which will display the pairing dialog again. I would suggest you retry a few times, say 3, in case the user made an error entering the PIN.

Comment: I have used your suggestion and did this in `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic`:
` if(error.domain == CBATTErrorDomain && error.code == 5){[managerCentral cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];}`
I guess this is the right way to go?